# SCCM - script still running

Tags: powershell, certificate, sccm

I've deployed powershell script that was writing information of user certificates on shared folder. I've deleted deployment but script is still running on computers and writing in that file. Do you know, how can I diagnose why scprit is still runing, or how can I end it? Attached script below.

Daniel

```
$report = @()
$certs = Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\my -Recurse |
  select @{n="Name"; e={$_.GetName()}}

$report +=  $env:computername+”;”+$env:username+”;”+$certs[0]+”;”+$certs[1]+”;”+$certs[2]
$report > \\server\certs.csv
```

Comment: Looks like a simple enough script.. Just kill all the `powershell.exe` processes to end it.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 problem is that this script is working after half a month after stoping deployment. It was sent to all computers in organization and there are still computers which saves certificates, even when they sent information before.

Comment: Aee you saying that *instances* of this script have been running continuously for weeks? Or do you mean that computers are still *running* this script despite the deployment having been removed? How was the script deployed? What triggers the execution of the script? GPO? Scheduled task? Login script? Startup script?

Comment: @veefu The second option, computers are still runing this script after it have been removed.
We use method from belowe article and it should execute just once:
https://www.systemcenterdudes.com/sccm-deploy-powershell-script/
I will try delete it manualny form this folder, but I think this can't be normal operation to do:
C:\Windows\CCM\ScriptStore

Comment: @p0p0s The code in the script says nothing about *how* the code is run and nothing in the script says "Run this script every day/hour/minute". So the answer you seek is somewhere else. You will probably need to provide further detail about how you built the deployment so people familiar with SCCM can analyze.

Comment: @veefu the only thing that I think can be a clue, is that after the deployment we have many errors saying that script wasn't excecuted but we get good data. I don't know if SCCM get error, it will try execute script again.

Comment: The link you provided says that scripts executed this way run under SYSTEM, but your script seems to be reading from the "user" certificate store. I don't know whether it explains why the script keeps getting run, but it is a sign that your script may not be doing what you intended. Are you trying to retrieve *user*-installed certificates?

Comment: You could try adding adding a pair of `Start-Transcript` and `End-Transcript` to the top and bottom of the script, along with some local filename. The transcript may capture some error messages with additional clues.

Comment: One last note: You might want to save the data in different files on a per-computer basis, then collate the results later. I wouldn't want hundreds or thousands of computers all trying to write to the same file at the same time. In fact, file locking *might* be the source of the problem.

Comment: @veefu we did it to get user certificates, so script needed to be set to execute when user was logging. I must check this again.Thak you for your response!